# How to create a new dataframe with groupby and min

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following fields:

```
week
zipcode
cost
```

I would like to create a new DataFrame from the above DataFrame ("week", "zipcode", and "min_cost") by performing the following SQL:

```
SELECT week, zipcode, MIN(cost) min_cost
FROM the_first_dataframe
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

My constraint is that I can't use pandasql and hope to achieve just by pure pandas operations.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: You can just use pandas group by functionality https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby` + named aggregation:

```
out = the_first_dataframe.groupby(['week','zipcode'], as_index=False).agg(min_cost=('cost','min'))
```

Comment: wouldnt the following be simpler? `df.groupby(['week','zipcode'])['cost'].min()`, with an optional `.reset_index()` at the end

Comment: @oskros it is but apparently OP wants to name the minimum cost column "min_cost"

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it

option1 :Use groupby agg and add to frame

```
 the_first_dataframe.groupby(['week','zipcode'])['cost'].agg('min').to_frame('min_cost')
```

option 2 :groupy, cost will be carried over. Rename it

```
the_first_dataframe.groupby(['week','zipcode']).min().rename(columns={'cost':'min_cost'})
```